# Third-party library as React's source of truth

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I wonder how to work with React when I am forced to use a third-party library that owns data. I want to consider it a source of truth, but the library is neither aware of React nor has an immutable state. As an example, consider the following todo-list as the third-party library I want to preserve untouched.

```js
class TodoList {
    items = ["dishes", "trash", "shop"];

    addRandomItem() {
        this.items.push(Math.random().toString());
    }
}
```

I want to achieve a situation where clicking a button adds a new item and re-renders the list.

Please consider this as a simple example. The best would be some kind of interlayer handling both function calls and components updates but I am curious how this problem is solved in other projects if occurs.

Comment: What calls `addRandomItem`?

Comment: Let's say I want to bind it to a button. So after clicking the button, the function adds a new item to the array but it won't re-render a component that renders those items because no one called `setState` or re-render equivalent.

Comment: Ok, so the solution seems pretty straightforward - the third party library isn't your source of truth, your actual source of truth is react whos initial state comes from the library. Whenever you update react's state, by say, adding a random item, you 1) update react's state and 2) call the appropriate method in the third party library.